# show '0' instead of null when select count is null

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

table_1                          table_2

```
 uid | eid | cid             cid | eid | name
----------------             ----------------
  20 | 1  |  3                1  |  1  | Amy
  20 | 1  |  2                2  |  1  | Sam
  20 | 1  |  3                3  |  1  | Paul
  20 | 2  |  1                4  |  2  | June
  20 | 2  |  2                5  |  2  | Peter
  20 | 2  |  2                6  |  2  | Mary
```

I need the following result:

```
name  | number
--------------
Amy   |   0
Sam   |   1
Paul  |   2
```

My code is

```
select t2.`name` , t2.cid, a.number from table_2 t2 
left join  table_1 t1 on t2.eid = t1.eid 
left join (select t12.cid, count(t12.cid) as number from table_1 t12
inner join table_2 t22
where t12.eid = 1 and t12.cid = t22.id group by t12.eid)a  on t2.id = a.cid 
where t1.eid = 1 group by t2.id
```

what I get is

```
name  | number
--------------
Amy   |  null
Sam   |   1
Paul  |   2
```

It doesn't not work if I use

```
IFNULL(count(t12.cid),0)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

On the PHP side, you can do this:

```
echo $some_var_that_may_be_null ?: 0;
```

This will cause any falsy values (in this case, null) to become zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
..., IFNULL(a.number, 0) AS number ...
```

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work , it shows nothing even the non null value

Answer (score 1):

you could also do:

```
CASE WHEN count(t12.cid) IS NOT NULL 
       THEN count(t12.cid)
       ELSE 0
END AS some_count
```

OR

```
(count(t12.cid) IS NOT NULL) AS some_count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Using  IF(count(t12.cid)= 'null', 0, count(t12.cid))
```